# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sin'

Tags: python

I've search for a few days but nothing worked, each time I try to run my code I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

I've tried everything but hopefully someone will find how to fix it

My code:

```
import pygame, sys, time
import math

from math import sin

from random import *

from time import *

from pygame import *

from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()

Blur = False

# Dead Or No Dead

not_dead = True

# Default Life Up Score

life_up = 100

# Heart PNG

heart_image = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Desktop/heart_image.bmp')

# Font

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("robotocondensed", 40)

# Pop Up Heart Variables

pop_up1 = True

pop_up2 = True

pop_up3 = True

pop_up4 = True

pop_up5 = True

pop_up6 = True

pop_up7 = True

pop_up8 = True

pop_up9 = True

pop_up10 = True

# Start Score

Score = False

score = 0

# Boulder Size Along With Max Boulder Size

B_size = 30

max_B_size = 59

# Start Life

life = 5

# Default max / min Boulder Speed

max_B_speed = 29

min_B_speed = 10

# Create Window

window_width = 1000

window_length = 700

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(((window_width), (window_length)))

# Toggle Damage (Use Invincibility For No Damage)

yes = False

# Toggle Invincibility

Invincibility = False

# Color Variables

RED = (255, 0, 0)
DARK_RED = (51, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE= (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BROWN = (101, 67, 33)
LIGHT_BROWN = (98, 64, 30)

# Boulder's(Blur) Color

B_Color = BROWN

BLUR_Color = LIGHT_BROWN

# Player's Color

playerColor = (WHITE)

# Variable for -30

z = -30

x = 1

# Blur Options

s = pygame.Surface(((B_size),(B_size)))

s.set_alpha(40)

s.fill(((RED)))

# Power Up 

toggle = True

power_up = True

level = 2

paused = False

direction = 4

## CLASSES


def polygon(sides, radius=1, rotation=0, translation=None):
    one_segment = 3.14 * 2 / sides

    points = [
        (math.sin(one_segment * i + rotation) * radius,
         math.cos(one_segment * i + rotation) * radius)
        for i in range(sides)]

    if translation:
        points = [[sum(pair) for pair in zip(point, translation)]
                  for point in points]

    return points


# Player Class

class Player (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.x = (window_width / 2)
        self.y = 670
        self.width = 30
        self.height = 5
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 30, 5)

        self.rect.move_ip(0,self.y)
        self.rect.move_ip(29,0)


    def handle_keys(self):

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        speed = 10

        print(self.x)


        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(speed *-1,0)
            self.x = self.x - 1

        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(speed,0)
            self.x += 1
    def draw(self, surface):

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (playerColor), self.rect)


    def window_border(self):
        speed = 10
        if (self.x == 560):
            self.rect.move_ip(speed * -1,0)
            self.x = (self.x - 1)

        elif (self.x == 497):
            self.rect.move_ip(speed,0)
            self.x = (self.x + 1)



# 1st Boulder Class

class Boulder(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = -70 #randint(56, 124)
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, 0, (B_size), 1))
        self.blur = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, 0 + z, (B_size), (B_size)))
        self.y = -30
        self.speed = 16 #randint((min_B_speed), (max_B_speed))
        self.size = (B_size)
        self.direction = 4

    def draw(self):

        if(level == 2):

            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, BROWN,(polygon(7,15, self.direction,[self.x, self.y])) , 0)

            self.direction += .005

    def updater(self):

        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, self.y, (B_size), (B_size)))

        #self.polygon = pygame.polygon.Polygon((self.x, 0, (B_size), (B_size)))



    def move(self, speed):

        self.y += (self.speed)

    def back_to_top(self):

        if (self.y >= 770):
            self.y = -30 
            self.x = randint(0, 660)
            self.speed = randint((min_B_speed), (max_B_speed))


# 2nd Boulder Class

class Boulder_2(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 30
        self.x = -70 
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, 0, (self.size), 5))
        self.y = -30
        self.speed = randint((min_B_speed), (max_B_speed))
        print("5")

    def draw(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (B_Color), self.rect)

        if (self.speed >= 20):

            screen.blit(s, (self.x, self.y + z))

    def updater(self):
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, self.y, (B_size), (B_size)))         

    def move(self, speed):

        self.y += (self.speed)

    def back_to_top(self):

        if (self.y >= 770):
            self.y = -30
            self.x = randint(0, 660)
            self.speed = randint((min_B_speed), (max_B_speed))


# 3nd Boulder Class

class Boulder_3(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = -70
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, 0, 30, 30))
        self.y = -30
        self.speed = randint((min_B_speed), (max_B_speed))


    def draw(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (B_Color), self.rect)

        if (self.speed >= 20):

            screen.blit(s, (self.x, self.y + z))

    def updater(self):



        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, self.y, (B_size), (B_size)))

    def move(self, speed):

        self.y += (self.speed)

    def back_to_top(self):

        if (self.y >= 770):
            self.y = -30
            self.x = randint(0, 660)
            self.speed = randint((min_B_speed), (max_B_speed))

# 4th Boulder Class 

class Boulder_4(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = -70 
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, 0, 30, 30))
        self.y = -30
        self.speed = randint((min_B_speed), (max_B_speed))


    def draw(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (B_Color), self.rect)

        if (self.speed >= 20):

            screen.blit(s, (self.x, self.y + z))

    def updater(self):

        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, self.y, (B_size), (B_size)))

    def move(self, speed):

        self.y += (self.speed)

    def back_to_top(self):

        if (self.y >= 770):
            self.y = -30
            self.x = randint(0, 660)
            self.speed = randint((min_B_speed), (max_B_speed))

class Boulder_5(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = -70
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, 0, (B_size), (B_size)))
        self.blur = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, 0 + z, (B_size), (B_size)))
        self.y = -30
        self.speed = 16 #randint((min_B_speed), (max_B_speed))
        self.size = (B_size)

    def draw(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (BROWN), self.rect)

    def updater(self):

        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, self.y, (B_size), (B_size)))

        if (self.speed >= 20):

            screen.blit(s, (self.x, self.y + z))

    def move(self, speed):

        self.y += (self.speed)

    def back_to_top(self):

        if (self.y >= 770):
            self.y = -30 
            self.x = randint(0, 660)
            self.speed = randint((min_B_speed), (max_B_speed))


# Floor Class

class Floor(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.x = 0
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, 0, 1000, 1))
        self.y = 750

# Border Class

class Big_Blue_Line(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.x = 700

        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, 0, 2, 1000))

    def draw(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (BROWN), (self.rect))


class Power_Up(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.timer = 0

        self.x = -50

        self.y = 0

        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, 0, 30, 30))

    def draw(self):

        screen.blit(heart_image,(self.x, self.y))

    def location(self):

        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.x, self.y, 20, 20))



        if (power_up == True):

            self.y += 10

            if (self.y >= 770):

                self.timer += 1

                self.y = -30

                print(self.timer)

                self.x = randint(-50, -49)

            if (self.timer >= 15):

                self.x = randint(30, 650)

                self.timer = 0





# Clock Variable

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Calling Instances

power = Power_Up()

player = Player([20, 20])

boulder = Boulder()

boulder2 = Boulder_2()

b3 = Boulder_3()

b4 = Boulder_4()

b5 = Boulder_5()

Floor = Floor()

Border = Big_Blue_Line()

#Main Game Loop

while True:

    window_width = window_width

    window_length = window_length

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.flip()


    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    if (paused == False):

        if (not_dead == False):

            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            GameOvertext = myfont.render("Game Over", 1, (255,255,255))

            screen.blit(GameOvertext, (430, 350))

            screen.blit(scoretext, (786, 60))

            Retrytext1 = myfont.render("RETRY?", 1, (255,255,255))

            screen.blit(Retrytext1, (450, 400))

            Retrytext2 = myfont.render("Y     N", 1, (255,255,255))

            screen.blit(Retrytext2, (460, 450))

            if key[pygame.K_y]:

                not_dead = True

                B_size = 30

                score = 0

                life += 5

                max_B_speed = 29

                min_B_speed = 10

            if key[pygame.K_n]:

                pygame.quit()

                sys.exit()

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:

            if (paused == False):


                paused = True

            else:

                paused = False


    if (not_dead == True) or (paused == False):


    ## HEALTH UP

        if (life <= 9):

            if score == (life_up):
                # Life Increase
                    life += 1

    ## Max / Min Boulder Speed Increase

        if score == (life_up):

            if (max_B_speed <= 49):

                max_B_speed += 2

                if (min_B_speed <= 46):

                    min_B_speed += 2


    ## Boulder Size Increase

        if score == (life_up):

            if (B_size <= (max_B_size)):

                B_size += 5

            life_up = (life_up) + 100

    ## COLLISION

        if (life <= 10):

            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, power):
                life += .5



        if (Invincibility == False):

            if yes == True:

                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, boulder):
                    life -= .5

                    print("HIT!")

                    yes = False

                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, boulder2):
                    life -= .5

                    yes = False


                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, b3):
                    life -= .5

                    yes = False


                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, b4):
                    life -= .5

                    yes = False

                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, b5):
                    life -= .5

                    yes = False

            else:
                clock.tick(9999999)
                yes = True

    ## DEATH

        if (life < 1):

            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

            GameOvertext = myfont.render("Game Over", 1, (255,255,255))

            not_dead = False

    ## SCORE TRACKER

        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(b5, Floor):
            score += 1


        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(b4, Floor):
            score += 1


        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(b3, Floor):
            score += 1


        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(boulder2, Floor):
            score += 1


        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(boulder, Floor):
            score += 1


    ## CLEAR SCREEN    

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))


    ## HEATH BAR

        if (life >= 10):

            screen.blit(heart_image,(950,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(925,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(900,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(875,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(850,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(825,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(800,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(775,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(750,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(725,10)) 

        if (life >= 9):

            screen.blit(heart_image,(950,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(925,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(900,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(875,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(850,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(825,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(800,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(775,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(750,10))

        if (life >= 8):

            screen.blit(heart_image,(950,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(925,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(900,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(875,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(850,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(825,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(800,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(775,10))          

        if (life >= 7):

            screen.blit(heart_image,(950,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(925,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(900,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(875,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(850,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(825,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(800,10))

        if (life >= 6):

            screen.blit(heart_image,(950,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(925,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(900,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(875,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(850,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(825,10))

        if (life >= 5):

            screen.blit(heart_image,(950,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(925,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(900,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(875,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(850,10))

        if (life >= 4):

            screen.blit(heart_image,(950,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(925,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(900,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(875,10))

        if (life >= 3):

            screen.blit(heart_image,(950,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(925,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(900,10))

        if (life >= 2):

            screen.blit(heart_image,(950,10))
            screen.blit(heart_image,(925,10))

        if (life >= 1):

            screen.blit(heart_image,(950,10))


    ## SCORE DISPLAY

        scoretext = myfont.render("Score {0}".format (score), 1, (255,255,255))

        screen.blit(scoretext, (786, 60))


    #INSTANCE FUCTIONS

        # Boulder Functions

        power.draw()

        power.location()

        boulder.updater() 

        boulder2.updater()

        b3.updater()

        b4.updater()

        b5.updater()

        boulder.draw()

        boulder2.draw()

        Border.draw()

        b3.draw()

        b4.draw()

        b5.draw()

        boulder.back_to_top()

        boulder2.back_to_top()

        b3.back_to_top()

        b4.back_to_top()

        b5.back_to_top()

        boulder.move(surface)

        boulder2.move(surface)

        b3.move(surface)

        b4.move(surface)

        b5.move(surface)

        # Player Functions

        player.draw(surface)

        player.handle_keys()

        player.window_border()

        pygame.display.update()

        player.update()

        s = pygame.Surface(((B_size),(B_size)))

        s.set_alpha(40)

        s.fill(((RED)))

        clock.tick(40)
```

The end result of my game is a paddle on the lower level of the screen and squares falling down that the player has to dodge, what I'm trying to do is make the square's amount of sides increase to a certain amount but every time I get the error stated above.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've already imported `math`. Remove the extra import and just call `math.sin()`

Answer (score 1):

You're first importing `math`, then everything from `pygame`. This results in importing `pygame.math` as `math`.

The result is that you're importing [a module](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) which does not have a `sin` function. That's also one of the reasons python zen says:

> Explicit is better than implicit

Since you already imported `pygame` on its own, you can qualify its members (which you seem to be doing anyway) and remove the `from ... import *` lines. Alternatively you could import only the things you actually want to use, like you do for `from pygame import mixer`.

`from ... import *` can bite you unexpectedly and it's better not to use it if you don't have to.